# Idiomatic way of finding functions in a namesspace containing specific metadata?

Tags: clojure, namespaces

I'm trying to figure out the best way to troll a namespace for functions that contain a specific bit of metadata. I've come up with a solution, but it feels a little awkward and I'm not at all sure I'm going about it the right way. There's a second component to this as well: I don't just want the names of the functions, I want to find them and then execute them. Here's a snippet of what I'm doing presently:

```
(defn wrap-routes
  [req from-ns]
  (let [publics (ns-publics from-ns)
        routes (->>
                (keys publics)
                (map #(meta (% publics)))
                (filter #(= (:route-handler %) true))
                (map #(:name %)))
        resp (first
                (->>
                  (map #((% publics) req) routes)
                  (filter #(:status %))))]
    (or resp not-found)))
```

As you can see, I'm doing all sorts of gymnastics to see if my metadata is attached to any functions in a given namespace and then am doing extra work after that to get the actual function back. I'm sure there must be a better way. So my question is, how would you do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(defn wrap-routes [req from-ns]
  (or (first (filter :status
                     (for [[name f] (ns-publics from-ns)
                           :when (:route-handler (meta f))]
                       (f req))))
      not-found))
```

Comment: This returns the `not-found` response every time so something isn't quite right. Does look more elegant however. (Also wouldn't it be better to use `fname` instead of `name`? Probably doesn't matter too much in this limited scope, but...)

Comment: I think this works, however: `(defn wrap-routes* [req from-ns]
  (or (first (filter :status
                     (for [[_ f] (ns-publics from-ns)
                           :when (:route-handler (meta f))]
                       (f req))))
      not-found))`

Comment: Oh, of course. I forgot where metadata is stored, I guess. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
(defn wrap-routes
  [req from-ns]
  (->> (ns-publics from-ns)
       (filter #(:route-handler (meta (%1 1))))
       (map #((%1 1) req))
       (filter #(:status %))
       first
       (#(or % not-found))))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is much more compact. For some reason I was having an issue getting the key out of the ns-publics map, which is why my solution became so convoluted. Maybe I was just missing the obvious. Anyway, most appreciated!